# Angular 2 form elements' attributes - correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, angular

I was reading [this artcle](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) and in the article I see:

> `<input type="search" [formControl]="seachControl">`

and

> `<input type="text" formControlName="street">`

I am wondering what the correct syntax is for stating `formControl` and `formGroup`. Can I do something like

`<input type="text" [formControlName]="street">`

or

`<input type="text" [attr.formControlName]="street">`

or

`<input type="text" [formControl]="street">`? And more specifically how do the three instances differ?

Answer (score 0):

`[formControl]="seachControl"` is what we call model binding, it's binding to the main form element i.e. search.

When you have a single form Element, i.e. `search` you're just simply model binding it to whatever `variable` you created inside your `class` and do keep in mind the type of the variable you bind to.

and as for the

```
<input type="text" formControlName="street">
```

since `street` here was created inside the main formControl element you don't have direct access to `street` variable. so what this directive is doing is telling that the main/parent element that this tag is should bind to the `street` you created inside the main `formControl`.

As for

```
<input type="text" [formControlName]="street">
```

I don't know but I think the `formControlName` doesn't actually do the binding it is sort of telling what this tag needs to bind to. And the syntax suggests that it will try to look for street variable inside your class bind it.

as you can see he says.

> This is where the `formControlName` directive comes into play. It’s pretty much the equivalent of an `ngModel` and `name` attribute combination in template-driven forms. Each form control gets a `formControlName` directive applied so we can register the controls on the ***outer form***

So you only need to bind the outer model since that exists/instantiated in your `class` and `formControlName` and `formGroupName` will take care of the inner elements.

Comment: this is all so confusing. for instance, it isn't quite clear to me whether `formControlName` is created as a property on the  component's class or not